# Turbain and CoroutineTest with delay throws TimeoutCancellationException

Tags: kotlin, testing, junit, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to test a flow with a delay by using [Turbain](https://github.com/cashapp/turbine) and CoroutineTest library. Does anybody know What I am missing here?

```
    @Test
    fun test(){
        val flow = flow<Int> {
            emit(1)
            delay(1000)
            emit(2)
        }

        runBlockingTest {
            flow.test(Duration.INFINITE) {
                expectItem()
                expectItem()
                expectComplete()
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the error I am getting.

```
kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutCancellationException: Timed out waiting for 9223372036854775807 ms
```

Comment: from all i know about turbine and a [comment in their tests](https://github.com/cashapp/turbine/blob/trunk/src/jvmTest/kotlin/app/cash/turbine/jvmTestUtil.kt#L30)
it seems like the time advancement feature of coroutine-test breaks turbine

for test using turbine i would recommend to use `runBlocking` or the `jvmSuspendTest` implementation from the turbine tests

Answer (score 0):

use **cancel()** instead of **cancelAndIgnoreRemainingEvents()** to Cancel collecting events from the source Flow and ignore any events which have already been received. Calling this function will exit the test block.
for more info check [here](https://cashapp.github.io/turbine/docs/0.x/turbine/app.cash.turbine/-flow-turbine/index.html#2223233%2FFunctions%2F788909594)

```
        @Test
        fun test(){
            val flow = flow<Int> {
                emit(1)
                delay(1000)
                emit(2)
            }
    
            runBlockingTest {
                flow.test(Duration.INFINITE) {
                    expectItem()
                  // verify using Assertions or whatever you want
                    cancel() //to cancel the flow
                }
            }
```